# Getting ITMS-4238 “Redundant Binary Upload” whenever trying to upload app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

No matter what I change the version or build number to in xCode I get this error code. When I change the version number it does not update when archiving the app.

E.g. I change 1.0 to 1.1 and everything in xcode shows up with the updated 1.1, but when I hit archive, the archived app shows 1.0.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your app already uploaded? Sometimes it take a while to to process the binary, so you might not see it in iTunesConnect for 10 minutes to 2-3 hours in my experience.

Comment: @Adrian the app was already uploaded but I am trying to update my app. I've changed the version and build number in xCode but this new version number is not appearing when trying to archive the project.

Comment: Have you configured it on iTunesConnect, too? On iTunesConnect, open your app and click "+ version or platform" to add the new version. If the version you uploaded from Xcode matches what's configured in iTunesConnect, you'll see a place to select the build in iTunesConnect.

Comment: @Adrian Yeah I have the updated build set up in iTunesConnect. I think the problem is that the archive is not being created with the updated version number (picture 2). I don't know why this is happening and I can't seem to find any other threads about this specific problem.

Comment: @Adrian I figured it out and will post the answer soon. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears I was updating the wrong part of settings. On the top bar on the left hand side where it says "General Capabilities etc." where it has your app name. I was updating the target with the round E instead of the one with the App Store symbol. Don't really know what the difference is but as soon as I changed the target my archive reflected the new version number.